# Texture paint output file format

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, export, texture-painting

I used texture paint option to paint over some 3d model. I would like to have a way to differentiate the different colored areas on the model based on something that I can code. To that end, I tried exporting the painted model as a Wavefront .OBJ file. It does give me a companion .MTL file but I'm not entirely sure if that gives me what I want to achieve. Neither does the .OBJ file, at least from what I understand.

Are there any other export file formats from which I may be able to get the color information in some alphanumeric values? Or is it possible to do so with the .OBJ file?

Comment: You can directly export image textures in a raster format like PNG, you simply need to unpack your files

Comment: @Gorgious how do you unpack the PNG?

Comment: You can just save the image externally with `ALT` + `S`.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka Could you please elaborate? In Blender with ALT + S there comes a little dialogue bubble at a corner saying "Packed to memory image "" ." Then what?

Comment: That means your image is packed inside blender. If your image is packed, you can press `SHIFT` + `ALT` + `S` to save it externally. It will pop up a dialog that allows you to save it to a location of your choice.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka So how to get the color information from the PNG? I already had the PNG. What I want to get is the color info in some alphanumeric values. I tried to open the PNG file in a notepad but that didn't work.